# is there any way to modify the following Snapshot class so that an arry stored in the snapshot is not affected by modifications to the original array

Tags: javascript

> class Snapshot {
> constructor(array) {
> this.array = array;
> }
> restore() {
> return this.array;
> }
> }
>
> var array = [1, 2];
> var snap = new Snapshot(array);
> array[0] = 3;
> array = snap.restore();
> console.log(array.join()); // It should log "1,2"
> array.push(4);
> array = snap.restore();
> console.log (array.join()); // It should log "1,2"

Comment: Hi, I think the attached answer is not similer to my question anymore! It is talking about obj and I am trying to ask about clasess...

Comment: No, the thing you’re trying to clone is an Array, not a class. An Array is just an Object. The JSON approach, the `structuredClone` approach, etc. still work for Arrays. More specifically, there’s `.slice` for shallow copies of Arrays, too. So `this.array = array.slice();` in the constructor would be a start.

Comment: Ok. Let me check and come back to you in case if any question.